# Latest technologies in java

Tags: java

I'm have an experience of 2+ in java development. I worked on corejava,toplink(db framework),sql.
I have knowledge on servlets,jsp and struts.

I would like to move to another company. What are the latest emerging technologies in java??

Comment: Belongs on `programmers.stackexchange.com`

Comment: I agree this should be moved. But however, he is going to get down vote from programmers.stackexchange.com as well - looks like even the moderators are confused as to where the sites do not overlap.

Answer (score 3):

A master is a master not because of his knowledge of the additional elements in his field; but, because of his skill in handling the core fundamentals.  All additional elements in a field stem from the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting into java as well. From what I have gleaned you should be well versed with the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org) and [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or other comparable tools (Google for alternatives). They aren't the "latest", but people will expect you to know them well.